# How do I move hard links to new server properly?

Tags: ubuntu, backup, rsync

I have a server with 4 drives in it and am getting pretty full. I run the drives in a raid 5 and they are all 3tb drives. I then run backintime and have it run my daily backup. My data set is about 3tb and my backups are right over 4tb.

Backintime uses hard links for its daily backups so that I get a full folder structure.

I want to setup a new server now and have the backups moved over to that server so that I can both free up space on my main storage server and also get my backups off my main server.

The problem is that I don't know how to move the files over to the new server and still have backintime recognize these are the same files. So when backintime runs on server 1 and backs up everything onto server 2, it needs to see that most of the files exist already instead of making duplicates. Because if I just move the files to the new server, and then have backintime run the backup and tell it to store it on the new server, it will create all new files for a full backup.

I hope this makes sense. How do I split these up but maintain my hard links that I currently have? If I lose that, I'll have a ton of wasted disk space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to move your snapshot to the new server manually (I assume both servers running Linux). You should use `rsync` for this on your old server

   ```
   rsync -avihH /path/to/backintime USER@NEW_SERVER:/path/to/
   ```

   This will take ages...
2. rename the `backintime` folder into `backintime.sic`on your old server. You can delete it later if everything works fine.
3. create a password-less login to your new server as described in `man backintime` section `Modes > SSH`
4. change mode `Local` to `SSH` in your existing profile in BackInTime and fill `Host`, `User`... fields
5. after closing `Settings` all your snapshots should show up again in Timeline. Create a new snapshot and you're done.

<sub>Disclaimer: I'm the current main Dev of BIT</sub>

Comment: Awesome.  I will try this when back at the office and let you know how it all goes. Thank you.

Comment: OK, my backups finally are rsync'd to the new server. When I try your method in backintime, it tells me to install sshfs

My understanding is that sshfs does not support hard links. Will I run into issues with this?

Comment: `sshfs` is not used for sync. Just to browse the snapshots.

Comment: Awesome. snapshot is running now. I will update this when it completes. I think it's working.